# ListenAndServeTLS runs locally but not in Docker container

Tags: docker, go

When running a Go HTTPS server locally with self signed certificates, things are fine
When pushing the same to a docker container (via skaffold -- or Google GKE), ListenAndServeTLS is hanging and the container is looping on recreation.

Certificate was create via:

```
openssl genrsa -out https-server.key 2048
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -out https-server.key
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key https-server.key -out https-server.crt -days 3650
```

main.go contains:

```
    if IsSSL {
      err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(addr+":"+srvPort, os.Getenv("CERT_FILE"), os.Getenv("KEY_FILE"), handler)
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
      }
    } else {
      log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(addr+":"+srvPort, handler))
    }
```

The crt and key files are passed via K8s secrets and my yaml file contains the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: google-cloud-key
          secret:
            secretName: ecomm-key
        - name: ssl-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ecomm-cert-server 
        - name: ssl-key
          secret:
            secretName: ecomm-cert-key   
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: gcr.io/sca-ecommerce-291313/frontend:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            httpGet:
              path: "/_healthz"
              port: 8080
              httpHeaders:
              - name: "Cookie"
                value: "shop_session-id=x-readiness-probe"
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            httpGet:
              path: "/_healthz"
              port: 8080
              httpHeaders:
              - name: "Cookie"
                value: "shop_session-id=x-liveness-probe"
          volumeMounts: 
          - name: ssl-cert
            mountPath: /var/secrets/ssl-cert
          - name: ssl-key
            mountPath: /var/secrets/ssl-key    
          env:
          - name: USE_SSL
            value: "true"  
          - name: CERT_FILE
            value: "/var/secrets/ssl-cert/cert-server.pem"
          - name: KEY_FILE
            value: "/var/secrets/ssl-key/cert-key.pem"                        
          - name: PORT
            value: "8080"
```

I have the same behaviour when referencing the file directly in the code like:

```
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(addr+":"+srvPort, "https-server.crt", "https-server.key", handler)
```

The strange and not helping thing is that ListenAndServeTLS does not give any log output on why it's hanging or a hinch on the problem ( using kubectl logs  )

Looking at the kubectl describe pod  output:

```
Name:         frontend-85f4d9cb8c-9bjh4
Namespace:    ecomm-ns
Priority:     0
Start Time:   Fri, 01 Jan 2021 17:04:29 +0100
Labels:       app=frontend
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=skaffold
              pod-template-hash=85f4d9cb8c
              skaffold.dev/run-id=44518449-c1c1-4b6c-8cc1-406ac6d6b91f
Annotations:  sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: true
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.10.7
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.10.7
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/frontend-85f4d9cb8c
Containers:
  frontend:
    Container ID:   docker://f867ea7a2f99edf891b571f80ae18f10e261375e073b9d2007bbff1600d272c7
    Image:          gcr.io/sca-ecommerce-291313/frontend:5110aa8a87655b07cc71ffb2c46fd8739e3c25c222a637b2f5a7a1af1bfccc22
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:5110aa8a87655b07cc71ffb2c46fd8739e3c25c222a637b2f5a7a1af1bfccc22
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 01 Jan 2021 17:05:08 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Fri, 01 Jan 2021 17:04:37 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 01 Jan 2021 17:05:07 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   64Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:8080/_healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8080/_healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:       /var/secrets/google/key.json
      CERT_FILE:                            /var/secrets/ssl-cert/cert-server.crt
      KEY_FILE:                             /var/secrets/ssl-key/cert-server.key
      PORT:                                 8080
      USE_SSL:                              true
      ONLINE_PRODUCT_CATALOG_SERVICE_ADDR:  onlineproductcatalogservice:4040  
      ENV_PLATFORM:                         gcp
      DISABLE_TRACING:                      1
      DISABLE_PROFILER:                     1
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-tm62d (ro)
      /var/secrets/google from google-cloud-key (rw)
      /var/secrets/ssl-cert from ssl-cert (rw)
      /var/secrets/ssl-key from ssl-key (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  google-cloud-key:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  ecomm-key
    Optional:    false
  ssl-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  https-cert-server
    Optional:    false
  ssl-key:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  https-cert-key
    Optional:    false
  default-token-tm62d:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-tm62d
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  46s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ecomm-ns/frontend-85f4d9cb8c-9bjh4
  Warning  Unhealthy  17s (x2 over 27s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 400
  Normal   Pulled     8s (x2 over 41s)   kubelet            Container image "gcr.io/frontend:5110aa8a87655b07cc71ffb2c46fd8739e3c25c222a637b2f5a7a1af1bfccc22" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    8s (x2 over 39s)   kubelet            Created container frontend
  Warning  Unhealthy  8s (x3 over 28s)   kubelet            Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 400
  Normal   Killing    8s                 kubelet            Container frontend failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Started    7s (x2 over 38s)   kubelet            Started container frontend
```

The liveness probe and readyness probes are getting a 400 response.

Comment: And what's the error that's returned?

Comment: no error returned. At least none in the container logs I could see. Just the container restarting over and over after some timeout period. Not sure where I can look for additional log info besides the kubectl logs <pod>

Comment: @Sebastian could you use and `kubectl describe <pod>` and share what you see there?

Comment: @shmsr good pointer: looks like the problem comes frome the readyness and liveness probes. Added the output in question above

Comment: So this was it: liveness and readyness probes were in HTTP, not HTTPS. Adding scheme: HTTPS in the yaml did it!

Comment: @Sebastian Cool!